# Proof cardinality of subset ≤ set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to proof if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets and $A \subseteq B$ then $|A| \leq |B|$.

I only have given these two definitions:

1. A finite set $A$ has a finite number of elements, and this number is called its cardinal, $|A|$
2. A set $A$ is a subset of a set $B$ if $x \in A$ implies that $x \in B$

I am not allowed to use any set operations like union, intersection etc. How would I do this?

Comment: If every element of A is an element of B, then the number of elements of A, that is equal to the number of elements of A that are elements of B is less-or-equal to the number of elements of B.

Comment: "A finite set $A$ has a finite number of elements" is a trash definition for the purposes of this proof unless it has also been defined what it means to have a finite number of elements.